# Twig print array value with variable index using attribute

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony4

I have a Twig global

```
globals:
    dayindex:
        1: 'Monday'
        2: 'Tuesday'
        3: 'Wednesday'
        4: 'Thursday'
        5: 'Friday'
        6: 'Saturday'
        7: 'Sunday'
```

Which I would like to access from twig using form collection field value.
If i try

```
{{ dump(attribute(dayindex, form.vars.value.day)) }}
```

I get 
**Key "" for array with keys "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" does not exist.**
even though {{ form.vars.value.day }} prints one of the keys.

The folowing code

```
{% set day = 1 %}
{{ form.vars.value.day }} - {{ day }}
{{ dump(attribute(dayindex, day)) }}
```

Prints out:

1 - 1

"Monday"

If I replace **day** with **form.vars.value.day** I get the mentioned error.

Comment: what is the underlying problem? what are trying to archieve?

Comment: I want {{attribute(dayindex, form.vars.value.day}} to print out Monday.
I want to create an <h5> tag holding the correspondent day name for respective day value.

Comment: Well your `form.vars.value.day` isn't correct and empty as suggest the error message. Display it to check its value. BTW the way it would be better to handle wit with translations.

Comment: I did, please read the last part of my post. The 1 - 1 testing.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough all my collection entries had valid values for day, the error was triggered when symfony was trying to create the prototype entry, which had a default null value for day.

```
{% if form.vars.value.day > 0 %}
    {{attribute(dayindex, form.vars.value.day | number_format) }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -2):

Could be that your variable is a string and that's why twig cant find such an index on your array.

Try:

```
{{ dump(attribute(dayindex, form.vars.value.day |  number_format)) }}
```

Comment: It changes it to zero. Key "0" for array with keys "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" does not exist. Seems like it takes it as empty even though printing it right above the function code line will give the day number value.